# Выделение слова

Tags: html

Как сделать так, чтобы нужное слово было на другом фоне?

Answer (score 3):

html:

```
Какойто текст и какоето особенное <span>СЛОВО</span>
```

css:

```
span {
    background:red; /*например пусть фон будет красный...*/
}
```

Или прямо в html:

```
Какойто текст и какоето особенное <span style="background:red">СЛОВО</span>
```

Comment: я б только в css выделил в отельный класс элемент span, например, span.colored {background-color: red;} и использовал в html как <span class="colored">Выделенное слово</span>

Comment: Я ответил на вопрос, по сути использование классов ID'шников и т.д. это уже тонкости...

Answer (score -3):

Смотри! Если тебе нужно выделить какую либо фразу или слово, но конкретно в HTML,

[***ВХОД или РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ***](http://1948csoolchat.ucoz.com/index/vkhod_ili_registracija/0-6)

Вот то что ты видешь выше - и есть пример(только он без форматирования из-з ссылки, с форматированием [на этом сайте](http://1948schoolchat.ucoz.com/index/glavnaja/0-4))
,а его код таков:

```
<p>
<a href="http://1948csoolchat.ucoz.com/index/vkhod_ili_registracija/0-6" target="_top"><span style="color:red"><span style="font-size: 36pt"><span style="font-size: 18pt"><strong><em><u><span style="background-color: #000000; color: #ffa500">ВХОД или РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ</span></u></em></strong></span></span></span></a><span style="color:red"><span style="font-size: 36pt"><span style="font-size: 18pt"><strong><em><u><span style="background-color: #000000; color: #ffa500"><br></span></u></em></strong></span></span></span></p>
```

Но здесь ссылка, и наверняка тебе не нужна эта надпись, и т.д.
Это легко поправить!

Берём код, и удаляем ненужное...

***текст (ВХОД или РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ)***

```
<p>
<span style="color:цвет подчёркивания(если не нужно - удали)"><span style="font-size: размер шрифта(пример:36pt)"><strong (Оставляешь, если нужен жир)><em><u><span style="background-color: цвет фона в 16ой системе (пример:#000000); color:цвет текста(пример:#ffa500)">текст (ВХОД или РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ)</span></u></em></strong></span></span></p>
```

Comment: глаза мои бы этого не видели, не html а страх господний >_<
не проще было сделать както так?
css:
    p {
       text-decoration:underline;
       color:#000;
       font-style:italic;
       font-weight:bold;
    }

    <p>текст(ВХОД или РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ)</p>

Comment: Дело в том что сайт-то на Юкозе!
А там КСС - единый на всё!!!

Comment: Дело в том что и в 1ом css можно нормально все прописывать, это раз.<br> <br>
ВО вторых - топик стартер не писала о том что у нее сайт на укозе, не?

Comment: кошмар.... многа многа букаф.. зачем столько, модераторы, просто оставить "как есть" это просто кошмар, только лишний код-лишний код-лишний код. ТС никогда так  не кодь! автору поста -

Comment: Да, нет! У меня все сайты на юкозе!
Я привёл пример как это можно сделать без КСС.
И отвечаю я как могу!

Comment: без обид, но советовать молодым кодерам нужно то, как нужно сразу делать правильно а не "как умеем" чтобы потом, когда вы будете ковырять чужой код, ем... ну как то так "ну что за м***к писал это г***о" и совершенно случайно наткнетесь на копирайт человека, которому Вы когда то посоветовали "как могли". Я же не лезу в темы, где ничего не понимаю или понимаю, но предложу один из самых паршивых вариантов ответа... ну в общем как то так. ответ должен быть емким но без воды. можно привести пример, простой, если не хватает знаний дать развернутый.. но не так.. вот чесс слово.

Comment: <small>Все уже поняли это :D</small>